# core.js:1440 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for . Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Tags: angular, angular4-router

not able to navigate to another routes after adding  in app.component.html

Code:

```
@NgModule({ 
  declarations: [ AppComponent, ProductComponent, MembersComponent ], 
  imports: [ 
    BrowserModule, 
    FormsModule, 
    HttpModule, 
    RouterModule.forRoot([ 
       { path: 'member', component: 'MembersComponent' },
       { path: 'product', component: 'ProductComponent' } 
    ]) ], 
  providers: [], 
  bootstrap: [AppComponent] 
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProductComponent,
    MembersComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'member',
        component: 'MembersComponent'
      },
      {
        path: 'product',
        component: 'ProductComponent'
      }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

Comment: add your code into your question

Answer (score 2):

seems your error is related to a dynamic component, check in which component you are calling something like `componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(someComponent)`. The value you are passing to that method should be included in your AppModule in a way like this:

```
@NgModule({ 
  declarations: [ AppComponent, ProductComponent, MembersComponent ], 
  imports: [ 
    BrowserModule, 
    FormsModule, 
    HttpModule, 
    RouterModule.forRoot([ 
     { path: 'member', component: 'MembersComponent' },
     { path: 'product', component: 'ProductComponent' } 
  ]) ], 
  providers: [],
  entryComponents: [someComponent]
  bootstrap: [AppComponent] 
 })
```